# Linux for armv8 - Avoid all idle processor states

Tags: linux, arm, armv8

I have a ARMv8 (Cortex A57) platform. I want to perform some performance measurements. For this I want to avoid all possible power idle states the processor has. Is there any kind of kernel config I can add to my .config to completely avoid idle|power_saving states?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check your kernel config has relevant configuration enabled.
Some boards of QC,MTK support that but others may not.

If your board supports this feature, you can disable the CPU idle state or cluster idle state ( depends on the specific SoC design ).

Here is an example for your commands in Linux kernel console for SMP cores:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/disable
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1/disable
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2/disable
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0/disable
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1/disable
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2/disable
```